# Replace link with form to pass variables to javascript / ajax - single script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm sending a single variable to javascript/ajax via a link, but want to send via a form so I can pass user input as well. (It's for a plugin that interfaces with an Echonest Remix python script to create audio edits). The short question is how can I receive this in a WP ajax javascript:

```
<form id="receive_me" method="POST">
Username: <input type="text" name="user_variable">
<input type="hidden" name="generated_var" value="'.$arguments.'">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The JS:

```
function glitch_player_display(generated_var) {
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxglitch_playerajax.ajaxurl,
        data: {
          action: 'ajaxglitch_player_ajaxhandler',
          mix_name: mix_name
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
          var showglitchplayer = '#showglitchplayer';
          jQuery(showglitchplayer).html('');
          jQuery(showglitchplayer).append(data);
        },
        error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert(errorThrown);
        }
      });
    }
```

This is the PHP current:

```
function glitch_player_show_make_mix(){
    $result = "";
    $generated_var = wp_create_nonce("ajaxloadpost_nonce");
    $arguments = "'".$nonce."'";
    $link = ' <div id="make_button"><a onclick="glitch_player_display('.$arguments.');">'. "Link Title" .'</a></div>';
    $result .= '<h3>' . $link . '</h3>';
    $result .=  '<div id="showglitchplayer">';
    $result .= '</div>';
    $result .= '<div id="play_button"><a title="The Title" href="'.plugin_URL.$generated_var.'.mp3">First Mix</a></div>';
    return $result;
}


add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxglitch_player_ajaxhandler', 'ajaxglitch_player_ajaxhandler' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajaxglitch_player_ajaxhandler', 'ajaxglitch_player_ajaxhandler' );

function ajaxglitch_player_ajaxhandler(){
    $generated_var = isset( $_POST['generated_var'] )? $_POST['generated_var'] : false;
    error_log( "The generated_var is $generated_var" ); // write it to the error_log too.)
```

But I'm not sure how to receive the POST to javascript. Something along these lines?

```
$('#inputForm').submit(function glitch_player_display(mix_name)
```

I don't need a second php script do I? I'll be grateful for a point further (or at all) in the right direction.

Thanks and stay well.

ANSWER: Based on input below, here ONE OF THE WAYS to send the variable via form:

```
<form id="form_id" name="form" method="post">
Field Title: <input type="text" id="user_input" size = 2>
<input type="hidden" id="mix_name" value="'.$arguments.'">
<input id="btn-submit" type="submit" onclick="glitch_player_display()" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And here's the JS/jQuery

```
function glitch_player_display() {
        user_input = document.getElementById("user_input").value ? document.getElementById("user_input").value : 2;
        generated_var = document.getElementById("generated_var").value ? document.getElementById("generated_var").value : "Default_Var";
        $(document).on('submit', '#form_id', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        jQuery.ajax({ 
            beforeSend: function() {
                alert(generated_var + " in ajax user_input: " + user_input);
            },
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxglitch_playerajax.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                action: 'ajaxglitch_player_ajaxhandler',
                generated_var: generated_var,
                user_input: user_input
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {play_button
                var showglitchplayer = '#showglitchplayer';
                jQuery(showglitchplayer).html('');
                jQuery(showglitchplayer).append(data);
            },
            error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
```

Note that we are not sending the variables to the js function `glitch_player_display()` as we were in the first case. We are picking it up within the JS function via `document.getElementById("user_input").value`. Also

```
beforeSend: function() {
                alert(generated_var + " in ajax user_input: " + user_input);
            },
```

Is just a way to test and see what the `jQuery.ajax` function is actually receiving. And since we're not actually calling another script via the submit button, it is necessary to invoke

```
$(document).on('submit', '#form_id', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
        });
```

So jQuery (or JS?) doesn't think it should be finding another script and generate an error, which in this case replaced user_variable with [object Object]. The object could be viewed by using `console_log()` and I think it was a huge error object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to launch the ajax request you need to prevent default behavior of the form submit.

```
$('#inputForm').submit(function(e) {

     // Prevent submitting the form normal way 

     e.preventDefault();

     // Now call the function that handles the ajax request

     glitch_player_display();
})
```

You need to get the value from the form. You can do it either in your .submit event handler and pass the mix_name to your glitch_player_display(mix_name) function as an argument, or just call glitch_player_display() without arguments and get your value inside this function through jquery.  Than you're making ajax request to ajaxglitch_playerajax.ajaxurl .. process it on your server-side and return response from there.

Answer (score 1):

Your button should call your javascript function with an onclick="" parameter and the javascript function can access the fields using documet.getElementById("fieldname").value to do what you want with it. Just give each field an ID="fieldname", replacing "fieldname" with a unique ID for each one, which you then access with document.getElementById().

Comment: Would I add the document.getELementById within my function `function glitch_player_display(mix_name) {}`?

Comment: Wherever you need to access the element from. If glitch_player_display() is the function that needs to access the element value then that's where you put it. You treat the returned value from the getElementById like you would any other javascript variable.  I'm not sure I understand your code enough to say for sure where you would best put it, but I would think it would be the routine the link-click is calling, since that's where you need to access the elements.

Comment: almost there, man. but having trouble retrieving them via ajax now. `alert(mix_name + " num tracks: " + num_tracks);` shows both variables, but the script does not get past this part `jQuery.ajax({...},`. Am guessing that maybe the answer lies in `url: ajaxglitch_playerajax.ajaxurl`.

Comment: My javascript is pretty good, but I'm a little weak myself on jquery. is ajaxglitch_playerajax.ajaxurl defined somewhere?  Normally I tend to hardcode the script I'm calling.  I'm assuming ajaxglitch_playerajax.ajaxurl is a variable that points to a php script?

Comment: yes. i think it is pointing to the wordpress ajax class via this call `wp_localize_script( 'ajaxglitch_player', 'ajaxglitch_playerajax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );`added the current js above.

Comment: Went to the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and added `beforeSend: function( num_tracks ) {
    alert(mix_name + " num tracks: " + num_tracks);
   }` to the .ajax call. Ajax is seeing num_tracks as [object Object]...

Comment: Well, for testing you could replace the wordpress call with a simple "test.php" which would just output the variables or something, just to see if it works. Are you sure you've done the housekeeping work necessary to call into wordpress?  I know with Joomla I had to jump through a couple hoops first before I could utilize Joomla's environment.

Comment: thought about doing that, or even just going ahead and adding a second php script, but was able to get it working. answer posted above.